# How to retrieve source documents via LangChain's get_relevant_documents method only if the answer is from the custom knowledge base

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am making a chatbot which accesses an external knowledge base `docs`. I want to get the relevant documents the bot accessed for its answer, but this shouldn't be the case when the user input is something like "hello", "how are you", "what's 2+2", or any answer that is not retrieved from the external knowledge base `docs`. In this case, I want
`retriever.get_relevant_documents(query)` or any other line to return an empty list or something similar.

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain 
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = ''

custom_template = """
This is conversation with a human. Answer the questions you get based on the knowledge you have.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't, don't try to make up an answer.
Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
"""
CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(custom_template)

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Name of the language model
    temperature=0  # Parameter that controls the randomness of the generated responses
)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docs = [
    "Buildings are made out of brick",
    "Buildings are made out of wood",
    "Buildings are made out of stone",
    "Buildings are made out of atoms",
    "Buildings are made out of building materials",
    "Cars are made out of metal",
    "Cars are made out of plastic",
  ]

vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(docs, embeddings)

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm,
    retriever,
    condense_question_prompt=CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    memory=memory
)

query = "what are cars made of?"
result = qa({"question": query})
print(result)
print(retriever.get_relevant_documents(query))
```

I tried setting a threshold for the retriever but I still get relevant documents with high similarity scores. And in other user prompts where there is a relevant document, I do not get back any relevant documents.

```
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={"score_threshold": .9})
```

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77178370/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: @PeterMortensen what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to change the chain type to RetrievalQA and introduce agents and tools.

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Tool,initialize_agent
from langchain.agents.types import AgentType

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = ''

system_message = """
"You are the XYZ bot."
"This is conversation with a human. Answer the questions you get based on the knowledge you have."
"If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't, don't try to make up an answer."
"""

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Name of the language model
    temperature=0  # Parameter that controls the randomness of the generated responses
)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docs = [
    "Buildings are made out of brick",
    "Buildings are made out of wood",
    "Buildings are made out of stone",
    "Buildings are made out of atoms",
    "Buildings are made out of building materials",
    "Cars are made out of metal",
    "Cars are made out of plastic",
  ]

vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(docs, embeddings)

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key='input', return_messages=True, output_key='output')

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        verbose=True,
        return_source_documents=True
    )

tools = [
        Tool(
            name="doc_search_tool",
            func=qa,
            description=(
               "This tool is used to retrieve information from the knowledge base"
            )
        )
    ]

agent = initialize_agent(
        agent = AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        tools=tools,
        llm=llm,
        memory=memory,
        return_source_documents=True,
        return_intermediate_steps=True,
        agent_kwargs={"system_message": system_message}
        )

query1 = "what are buildings made of?"
result1 = agent(query1)


query2 = "who are you?"
result2 = agent(query2)
```

if result accessed sources, it will have values for the key `"intermediate_steps"` then source documents can be accessed through `result1["intermediate_steps"][0][1]["source_documents"]`

otherwise, when the query didn't need sources, `result2["intermediate_steps"]` will be empty.

Comment: the question you ask and your solution is conflicting each other. please update

Comment: @Damodhar To solve this question, I had to change the chain type to RetrievalQA and introduce agents and tools.

Comment: but the base problem is same still the similarity search will give you result, in your previous code you need to give rules to your llm for in context answering

Answer (score 0):

you need to add parameter in chain "return_source_documents" like below

```
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm,
    retriever,
    condense_question_prompt=CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    memory=memory,
    return_source_documents=True
)

query = "what are cars made of?"
result = qa({"question": query})
```

and in result you will get your source documents along with the scores of similarity

get all relevant documents

```
answer = result.get("answer")

docs = result.get("source_documents", [])
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue. I still get source documents when asking the bot who it is.

{'question': 'who are you?',
 'chat_history': '',
 'answer': 'I am an AI language model developed by OpenAI. How can I assist you today?',
 'source_documents': [Document(page_content='Buildings are made out of wood', metadata={}),
  Document(page_content='Cars are made out of plastic', metadata={}),
  Document(page_content='Buildings are made out of atoms', metadata={}),
  Document(page_content='Buildings are made out of stone', metadata={})]}

Comment: OK, i got your point very first u need to give llm answer in the your provided doc(like RAG), for this you need to chnage your prompt like   general_system_template = r"""
        Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer,
        just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
        ----
        {context}
        ----
        """

Comment: can you please illustrate that using an actual answer using the code provided?

Comment: if we provide the context to the llm and ask any question in that content it will give us the answer in that content please see the attached https://drive.google.com/file/d/14yAcT2wA4rj1eh8DG7-70RS0ik2jYjCy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in this image i am defining the rule to llm and ask the answer same you need to do for above code that will work

Comment: if you need the exact code ill attach in next comment, let me know if required of not

Comment: please submit an answer so that I can evaluate whether it satisfies my needs or not

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get the source docs URL:

```
for x in range(len(response["source_documents"][0].metadata)):
    print(response["source_documents"][x].metadata)
```

and also this version to format it better:

```
    for x in range(len(response["source_documents"][0].metadata)):
        raw_dict = response["source_documents"][x].metadata
        print("Page number:", raw_dict['page'], "Filename:", raw_dict['source'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading langchain to a version >0.1.1. I used [Blue Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15671914/blue-cheese)'s solution but the problem with using RetrievalQA is that it calls a combine_documents_chain which costs time and the result is discarded.
To only get the source documents I subclassed RetrievalQA. The documents are returned in `source_documents` and the original query is passed-through.

```
class RetrievalQAWithoutCombine(RetrievalQA):
def _call(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForChainRun] = None, ) -> Dict[
    str, Any]:
    _run_manager = run_manager or CallbackManagerForChainRun.get_noop_manager()

    query = inputs["query"]
    retriever_results = self.retriever.get_relevant_documents(query, callbacks=_run_manager.get_child())
    result = {"result": query, "source_documents": retriever_results}
    return result

async def _acall(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForChainRun] = None, ) -> \
        Dict[str, Any]:
    query = inputs["query"]
    _run_manager = run_manager or AsyncCallbackManagerForChainRun.get_noop_manager()
    retriever_results = await self.retriever.aget_relevant_documents(query, _run_manager.get_child())
    result = {"result": query, "source_documents": retriever_results}
    return result
```

You can use this as an in-place replacement of RetrievalQA in @blue-cheese answer.

I hope this helps someone.